# What Is it the correct syntax to set permission 'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' to avoid "message" : "Rate limit exceeded. User message:

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

```
function createPermissionOffic(auth){
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

  var fileId = rootFolderId;
  var permissions = [
    {
      'type': 'user',
      'role': 'writer',
      'emailAddress': 'someemailaddress@gmail.com'
    }
  ];
  // Using the NPM module 'async'
  async.eachSeries(permissions, (permission, permissionCallback)=> {
    drive.permissions.create({
      resource: permission,
      fileId: fileId,
      fields: 'id',
    }, (err, res)=> {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error...
        console.error(err);
        permissionCallback(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Permission ID: '+ res)
        permissionCallback();
      }
    });
  }, (err)=> {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      // All permissions inserted
      drive.permissions.insert(
        {
          'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
        });
    }
  });
```

I am getting below error : google drive API documentation does not elaborate much.here is the error I am getting.
TypeError: drive.permissions.insert is not a function at async.eachSeries

Comment: **Rate limit exceded** Is flood protection.  It isnt going to be effected by your sending email notifications. Its related to the speed your application is running you need to slow down.

Comment: I don't understand the point of using `'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'` to avoid this exception. Could you please expand on that? Also, have you checked [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_rate_limit_exceeded)?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_sharing_rate_limit_exceeded

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_sharing_rate_limit_exceeded  please follow this URL. it says:To fix this error:
1.Do not send emails when sharing lot of files.
2. If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a G Suite domain, consider a Service Account with authority delegation to impersonate the owner of each document to share (setting the quotaUser parameter).

Comment: My development significantly impacted due to this limit.  the permission insertion syntax suggested below worked. However I am not sure yet if this overcome rate limit problem. I am also trying to use service account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to use `sendNotificationEmail: false` for Permissions: create method.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to create the permission using Drive API v3.

#### Modification points:

- `drive.permissions.insert` is for Drive API v2. And in this case, when you run the script, an error occurs. In order to use `sendNotificationEmail: false`, please use it to `drive.permissions.create`.
- About `Rate limit exceeded`, when the array length of `permissions` is large, such error might occur. So at first, as a test, how about checking whether the request works using a simple situation. In your sample script in your question, the array length of `1` is used. I think that how about checking the request using it?
- In your case, the permission ID can be retrieved by `res.data.id`.
- In your script, `rootFolderId` is used at `var fileId = rootFolderId;`. When `rootFolderId` is the root folder ID, an error like `This file is never writable.` occurs. So please be careful this.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
const drive = google.drive({version: "v3", auth});

var fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID or folder ID.

var permissions = [
  {
    type: "user",
    role: "writer",
    emailAddress: 'someemailaddress@gmail.com',
  },
];

// Using the NPM module 'async'
async.eachSeries(
  permissions,
  (permission, permissionCallback) => {
    drive.permissions.create(
      {
        resource: permission,
        fileId: fileId,
        fields: "id",
        sendNotificationEmail: false,  // <--- Added
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error...
          console.error(err);
          permissionCallback(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Permission ID: " + res.data.id);  // <--- Modified
          permissionCallback();
        }
      }
    );
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Done");  // <--- Modified
    }
  }
);
```

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)